# How to change the Android gallery selected item color?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am trying to write a code to display Android gallery view with infinite list. I am able to display the gallery properly in the screen but i want to change the color of selected item in the gallery.

**MyCode:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mycircularlistview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Gallery;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String[] txtData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);


        txtData = new String[12];

        for(int i=0;i<txtData.length;i++){

            txtData[i] = ""+i;
        }

        gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryAdapter(this,txtData));

        gallery.setSpacing(18);


}


}
```

**GalleryAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.mycircularlistview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    String[] txtData;

    public GalleryAdapter(Context c, String[] txtData) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.txtData = txtData;
    }

    public int getCount() {

        if (txtData != null) {

            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        } else {

            return 0;

        }

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        if(position >= txtData.length) {

            position = position % txtData.length;

        }

        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        if(position >= txtData.length) {

            position = position % txtData.length;

        }

        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        TextView txt = null;

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, parent, false);

        txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtImg); 


        if(position >= txtData.length) {
            position = position % txtData.length;
        }


        txt.setText(""+txtData[position]+" :: "+position);


        return view;

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout1">

    <Gallery
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mygallery"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Screenshots :**

[image]

These are all the codes and screenshots of my issue. So , you can check in the screenshots that , there is always a set of 5 elements are there in the screen at a time , so i want to change the color of the middle index.

Please suggest me some solution.